# Android update online spreadsheet

Tags: android, database, excel, spreadsheet

I'm writing an app that will need to upload some basic data on an online spreadsheet. The app won't have to read or delete any data, it will just have to insert some data line by line. For example something like that:

```
.insertNewRow("Joe", "25", "Programmer");
```

What's the simplest way to do that? Google spreadsheets? Microsoft Excel Online? Firebase database?

I've read the google sheets api but there seems to be too much work involded with getting an OAuth authentication and more.

Is there a simple way to insert some data on the spreadsheet just by requiring the url of the sheet and the email address/password of the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I figured it out.

The simplest and easiest solution is to create a Google Form, instead of a spreadsheet and then send the data to the form using Http Post requests.

The form can be viewed as a spreadsheet online which you can also export to xlsx, csv, etc.

So that way, you can actually send data to an online spreadsheet without requiring any authentication.

There's a nice tutorial here: http://codesmith.in/post-data-google-drive-sheet-through-mobile-app/